# Inserting into a mysql table and overwritng any current data

Tags: mysql

I am inserting some data into a table, but it occasionally clashes with other data in the table (ie. it has the same primary key).
I would like to be able to just overwrite this data if it is there, instead of having mysql send me an error message saying that there is a duplicate primary key. I know that I can just delete these values beforehand, but it would take a somewhat large query.
Is it possible to overwrite these values and suppress any warnings, or am I forced to remove these values?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just a little cheatsheet.
Mysql has 3 different scenarios for handling unique key duplicates:

If you want to...

- do nothing - use `INSERT IGNORE`
- delete existing and create new - use [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)
- update existing - use [`ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: what's the difference between `REPLACE INTO` and `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`? It seems they have same results.

Comment: You should have also mentioned the side effects of each one. Because there are

Answer (score 6):

You can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) INTO in MySQL to do this.

```
REPLACE INTO table
SET name = 'Treffynnon'
```

Comment: I like the shameless self promotion.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL has a "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" command.
You can find it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('a', 'b') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field1`='a', `field2`='b'
```

Comment: `set field=VALUES(field)` is a better option - saves you having to use your data twice in the query. the values() function will pull it from the insert part of the statement for you, so your data only goes into the query string once.

Answer (score 1):

Look up "on duplicate key update".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **replace** statement instead of **insert**.
Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html