# "REPLACE INTO" versus INSERT [IF]

Tags: php, mysql, insert, replace

Alright, I've got a question, not really an issue.

I've got a table in my database, fairly small, only 3 columns but potential to grow. I've got two solutions to my problem, but not sure why to use one or the other.

I've got a piece of data, which might or might not already be in the database. Two ways to solve this. I've got the unique ID, so it is easy to check.

1. Check if the records exists in the database, and if not, `INSERT INTO` database
2. Use `REPLACE INTO`, because I've got the ID already.

My question now is. Which one is better to use. What are the pros and cons in using either of the 2 results. Or is there a better result?

A note, the data is exactly the same, so there is no chance the record gets updated with a newer value. Thus the `REPLACE INTO` will insert data which is already there.

Comment: Watch out, `REPLACE INTO` is implemented internally as a `DELETE` and then an `INSERT`.  The delete is a normal delete, meaning it will check foreign keys and obey `ON DELETE` clauses.  You *probably* want `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` instead anyway.

Comment: But, what is best practice here? And why

Comment: Additionally, if you attempt to update a row with the same (existing) values, MySQL will detect that the values are the same and will skip the update, saving time, locks, etc.--another reason to use `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` versus deleting the existing row first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting into a mysql table and overwritng any current data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206822/inserting-into-a-mysql-table-and-overwritng-any-current-data)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`REPLACE INTO` is not recommended here - you don't really need to replace anything. It does `DELETE` followed by `INSERT`, with all the consequences. For example all indexes have to be updated, which leads to unnecessary work and index fragmenting if you use it frequently.

On the other hand there is `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, which is used mainly for counters, but you are not updating your row with increments or any other value changes, so you would have to use weird syntax like `SET id=id` or something similar.

Checking if the record exists in the database would be the best solution for you, but instead of using another query let mysql do that check for you and use:

```
`INSERT IGNORE INTO ...`
```

This way if you try to insert any row with duplicated unique or primary key it simply won't be inserted without generating any error. Note the side effect of possibly missing other error messages, but if you know exactly what you insert you should be fine.