# PHP PDO Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: duplicates, primary-key

I'm trying to insert values into different tables at once. new data has never been inserted before to any of these tables and I get inserted into the first table only then get this error

```
Duplicate entry 'example@mail.com' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

code

```
include("../connect.php");
$this->con->exec('INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, "' . $this->email . '","' . $this->name . '","' . $pass . '",0,' . $this->isEmailConfirmed . ',"' . $this->token . '", "")');

//insert into another database
include("../another_directory/connect.php");
$this->con->exec('INSERT INTO users  VALUES (null, "' . $this->email . '","' . $this->name . '","' . $pass . '",0,' . $this->isEmailConfirmed . ',"' . $this->token . '", "")');
print_r($this->con->errorInfo());
```

null refers to the first field `user_id` which is `index` and set to `auto increment`. The email field is `primary key`. Now I'm trying to register users but the user get inserted into the first table only and cannot be inserted into the same table in the other database and get the duplicate primary error though it has never been added before.

I tried the traditional way of insert

```
insert into users (field1, field2) values ($value1, $value2)
```

But I get the same error.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: the `auto_increment` field must be the `primary key` surely?!! Your sql is vulnerable to sql injection though

Comment: Duplicate entry is telling you the error. The value is already in the database. You can't insert it again.

Comment: what is `//insert into another database` all about? Are you really trying to insert into different databases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting into a mysql table and overwritng any current data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206822/inserting-into-a-mysql-table-and-overwritng-any-current-data)

Comment: @RamRaider email is primary key and can't change it as it's related to other tables as foreign key (i didn't develop this script i'm just updating and adding more features)

Comment: @kainaw the error is triggered in the other database and this value never existed before

Comment: @RamRaider (i didn't develop this script i'm just updating and adding more features and it was something stupid the junior developer did and had to deal with it now)

Comment: @PHPUser Some code is better to be rewritten than fixed.

Comment: @PHPUser It is absolutely impossible to get that error if the value doesn't already exist. Therefore, it is unreasonable for anyone to assume that your installation is the problem when it is painfully obvious that you are trying to insert the same value more than once.

Comment: @kainaw it was the connection issue it was selecting the same database again.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov  so much code to be rewritten so fixes will cost less time and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe using diferent values for the conections:

```
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'database1';
$userdb = 'user';
$passdb = 'pass';

// Connection data2 (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb1 = 'localhost';
$namedb1 = 'database2';
$userdb1 = 'user';
$passdb1 = 'pass';

  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb1; dbname=$namedb1", $userdb1, $passdb1);

  $conn->exec('INSERT INTO users VALUES (null, "' . $this->email . '","' . $this->name . '","' . $pass . '",0,' . $this->isEmailConfirmed . ',"' . $this->token . '", "")');
  $conn1->exec('INSERT INTO users  VALUES (null, "' . $this->email . '","' . $this->name . '","' . $pass . '",0,' . $this->isEmailConfirmed . ',"' . $this->token . '", "")');

    print_r($conn->errorInfo());
    print_r($conn1->errorInfo());
```

Comment: Cannot re-assign $this